# Timer Service to run everyday 5 AM

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

Below is the code i am currently using to run every 5 minutes. Somebody help to setup at morning 5 AM everyday.

```
timerService.createTimer(invokeTime,
                5*60*1000, ProgramParticipantManagerBean.class.getName());
```

Comment: What's the question? "Somebody help" isn't very specific, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can use the [ScheduleExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/ScheduleExpression.html) as follows:

```
ScheduleExpression schedule = new ScheduleExpression();
schedule.dayOfWeek("[0,7]");
schedule.hour("05");
Timer timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule);
```

Or use the [@Schedules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedules.html) annotations.

**See more**:

- [Using the Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).

Comment: EJB is not supporting ScheduleExpression  and createCalendarTimer. It only supports createTimer

Comment: On which container? You have not given any information that can help anyone help you effectively.